# Verificar se table dinâmica está com dados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma `table` que preencho desta forma abaixo, gostaria de saber como posso verificar se tem dados na mesma.

```
  $("#tablepesquisaprodutos").append("<tr class='item'>"
             + "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' class='link-check' onchange='cbChange(this);' />" + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + CodigoProduto + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + DescricaoProduto + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + Qtd + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + PrecoCusto + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + DescontoP + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + DescontoV + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + Total.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + ICMS + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + AliquotaICMS.replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + vICMS.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + ISS.replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + vISS.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + vIPI.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + QtdFalta + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + ProdutoID + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + DataEntrega + "</td>"
             + "</tr>")
```

Já tentei de algumas formas, porém todas não identifica as linhas, pois são inseridas dinâmicas.

Comment: Tente assim: `if($("#tablepesquisaprodutos td").length){ // possui colunas }`... isso irá verificar se possui colunas `td`... caso queira ver se possui `tr` basta trocar o `td` por `tr`.

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode contar o número de colunas (`td`) com:

```
$("#tablepesquisaprodutos td").length
```

Se não encontrar nada irá retornar `0`, logo cabe num `if` a verificação:

```
if($("#tablepesquisaprodutos td").length){
   // possui ao menos 1 coluna
}
```